# wix Launch Condition for isapi&cgi restrictions

Tags: wix

My program needs isapi&cgi restrictions are installed in iis. I want a wix launch condition for isapi&cgi restrictions are installed or not. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to write a [custom action](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/authoring_custom_actions.htm) which detects if these restrictions are installed or not. Based on the result it can set an installer property which can be used as a launch condition.

You can find a custom action tutorial here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx

The custom action should be scheduled before [LaunchConditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369751%28VS.85%29.aspx) action and it should be Immediate.

Comment: Thanks cosmin. But i searcehd and didnt find any custom action for isapi&cgi installed. Can you help me in writing the custom action for isapi&cgi restrictions are installed

Comment: There are no predefined custom actions. You need to write one yourself using custom code. It can be an EXE, DLL or VBScript file.

Comment: is there any possible way to check the isapi and cgi restrictions are installed using c#. how can we check whether those are installed.

Comment: even if there is any possible way to allow my program if those are not installed.

Comment: "Handler "PageHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" has a bad module "IsapiModule" in its module list". this problem im getting if isapi and cgi are not installed. if that is installed then my program working fine